# ASP MVC load existing Session State based on SessionID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

When 3th party cookies are disabled in the browser, pages loaded into iframe have disabled cookies. When ASP MVC application resource is loaded in parent (main) window and the same application is loaded in iframe, later one doesn't send session cookies and so doesn't share session with top level page.

My first idea to solve this is to provide SessionID as parameter in the iframe url, and somehow based on that SessionID load existing Session State of top page.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net already have [cookieless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) Session option. You just need to turn on in web.config.

`<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

I have used the cookieless option in the passed in ASP.Net Web Form. I haven't really tested in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Thanks that was the option I was exploring, but it obviously modifies path part of url which I don't want to touch (we use IIS rewrites heavily). Unless there is a way to force asp to use query string to carry session ID.

Comment: I personally haven't tried adding SessionID in query string. However, you might want to look at Token Based Authentication which is more robust and works right out of the box. It is originally intended for Mobile App which cannot use cookie.